# Fetching value from a form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have this form that has a token given to the user by Laravel. I am trying to get the token in JavaScript but keep getting undefined when I access it using the following code:

```
$('#logout-form input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="logout-form" name="logout-form" action="http://localhost:8000/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="G34AAZxNMCADyETGhiXWqe3GGZQnPOfTHBFtZnUy">
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/dLkr792s/

Comment: working fine-> https://jsfiddle.net/vpjy8czj/

Comment: That's so odd. I've got the exact same code running on my local website and it just says undefined but works fine in jsfiddle. Maybe I should try a different approach?

Comment: can you please provide more code?

Comment: I'm not sure what else would be relevant? The hidden input is provided by Laravel using "{{ csrf_field() }}" but thats it

Comment: Show all code!!

Comment: check `jquery ` link in your localhost html page. because you javascript calling is jquery function.But the question not tag with jquery ?

Comment: What do you get if you run the jquery code for val in console log?

Comment: Using the jQuery document ready fixed my issue

Comment: He is probably searching for the text field *before* it is appended to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery method "val" get the text between tags, like texte
So, Use method "attr" to get attribute "value" from a input tag.

Example:

$('#logout-form input[type="hidden"]').attr('value');